# How do you translate 'preferring man' into Latin as 'wise man' is translated into Homo sapiens?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, neologism

My initial try was “Homo Praeferens”. What I mean by 'preferring man' is that we can always find the most favorite from a set of alternatives, which is the finding from my behavioral study. I think it could be a universal human nature and I want to express that by the Latin phrase.

Comment: What is the context of this "preferring man?" Homo sapiens is "man who is (being) wise." If you're looking for "man who is preferring," your translation might work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation that Homo praeferens means man who is preferring.  That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the verb "cernere", meaning "having the ability to distinguish (and operate a choice as a consequence)". Maybe something like *Homo cernit* (man decides), or *Homo crevit* (Here I use the perfect tense with a gnomic value, as in proverbs), that stands for "man has (always) choosen".
Or, if you prefer, *Homo semper crevit*.

If you prefer instead to use the participle to create a paronomasia, then *Homo cernens*.
Other interesting hues are:
*Homo diligens* (choosing, and with a certain preference and even respect, love);
*Homo eligens* (eligere means knowing how to choose, choosing with competence, and therefore nominate, elect, even in a figurative way);
*Homo optans* (choosing, tending or aspiring to something).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am very grateful for your suggestions. To be more detailed about the findings of the study, we found that the choices of the majority of participants ( by simple majority rule in 2AFC task) always made the perfect rank of the alternatives. That means there is always the most favorite candidate for the majority of people in any set of alternatives. How do you think using the word praeferre ‘carry in front’ since it explains well the finding and seems to have more familiarity than cernere or optans for the current readers of the article?

Comment: @Yong-WookShin In this context your alternative seems to me to fit perfectly! While *cernere* indicates a faculty of the human intellect, (and it is still present in languages such as Italian, where *cernita* = selection, sorting), *praeferre* is more strict in isolating one object from a whole set of possibilities. It is also more concrete, identifying an action, material or figurative, deliberated or even instinctive

Comment: Btw, your interesting study reminds me of Buridan's ass, which apparently is in fact a paradox in nature. Really a fascinating topic, if you please I'd like to read the article about this research once finished!

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful comments. If you let me know your email address, I can send you the draft or the link for the study.

Comment: @Yong-WookShin My pleasure! My address is luca.nr@libero.it

Comment: I like your suggestion, and I think it works. What I don't see is how it is preferable to *praeferens* or *malens* or *judicans* or whatnot.